# before_action in rails 4 with devise multiple user models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, models

Thanks for reading!
The problem seems easy to solve, but im fighting with it 4 hour, so:
Models:

```
class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
:recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

and same is for Pupil and Teacher classes, but with class Pupil < ActiveRecord::Base etc.

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :authenticate_pupil!
  before_action :authenticate_admin!
  before_action :authenticate_teacher!  

end
```

application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>EDziennik2</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<% if notice %>
  <p class="alert alert-success"><%= notice %></p>
<% end %>
<% if alert %>
  <p class="alert alert-danger"><%= alert %></p>
<% end %>

<p class="navbar-text pull-right">
<% if admin_signed_in? %>
  Logged in as <strong><%= current_admin.email %></strong>.
  <br>
  <%= current_admin %>
  <%= link_to 'Edit profile', edit_admin_registration_path, :class => 'navbar-link' %> |
  <%= link_to "Logout", destroy_admin_session_path, method: :delete, :class => 'navbar-link'  %>
<% elsif pupil_signed_in? %>
  Logged in as <strong><%= current_pupil.email %></strong>.
  <br>
  <%= current_pupil %>
  <%= link_to 'Edit profile', edit_pupil_registration_path, :class => 'navbar-link' %> |
  <%= link_to "Logout", destroy_pupil_session_path, method: :delete, :class => 'navbar-link'  %>
<% elsif teacher_signed_in? %>
  Logged in as <strong><%= current_teacher.email %></strong>.
  <br>
  <%= current_teacher %>
  <%= link_to 'Edit profile', edit_teacher_registration_path, :class => 'navbar-link' %> |
  <%= link_to "Logout", destroy_teacher_session_path, method: :delete, :class => 'navbar-link'  %>
<% end %>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

The problem is, that when Im trying to sign in, I need to pass email and password 3 times. Then im logged in correctly. For me it is a problem in application_controller.rb and lines with 3x before_action authentication, because when I delete 2 of them, im logging in correctly. Any ideas what to do?

**Edit:**
Ok, I think I have solved this problem :)
in application_controller.rb i have define new method, called

> authenticate!

```
def authenticate!
    if @current_user == current_admin 
        :authenticate_admin!
    elsif @current_user == current_pupil
        :authenticate_pupil
    elsif @current_user == current_teacher
        :authenticate_teacher
    end
  end
```